# Adding new Controller, Repositories and Model to the spring-cloud-dataflow-server

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are working on adding user management feature to spring-cloud-dataflow. I've added new Controller to the spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core project. It seems my controller is not getting called because, while making rest call as per RequestMapping param, the server is responding with 404.
How can I add new Controller, Repositories, and Model to the spring-cloud-dataflow-server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding this controller in your fork of SCDF core project? or, via a custom SCDF server project that uses SCDF core via @EnableDataFlowServer?

If you are making these changes in your fork, I believe you added your controller bean in the [DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/config/DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration.java#L148) and make sure your repositories are added to the `EnableJpaRepositories` and corresponding domain classes in the `EntityScan`.